# Скрыть все открытые блоки при клике по кнопке

Tags: jquery

Написал небольшой скрипт по раскрытию блоков с контентом:

http://jsfiddle.net/webphp/nb8ybczh/

Вроде все хорошо, но проблема начинается, когда открываешь более 2-х блоков на странице.

Необходимо закрыть все блоки, но только НЕ тот, который необходимо открыть. Как такие условия пишутся правильно? Или, быть может, я что-то изначально не так делаю.

Comment: Ищите все блоки - закрываете, текущий - открываете. В чем проблема то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще, обычно сначала закрывают все блоки, а потом открывают нужный.